# C Program - Validate numbers read from a text file

Tags: c, validation, scanf, file-read, procedural-programming

I am reading 15 numbers from a text file, with each number in a new line:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
12
13
14
15
21
22
23
24
26
```

As you can see from the code I need the numbers to be validated so they are less than 26, otherwise terminate the program.

At the moment I am validating only after inserting it to the array *(numArray)*. Is there a cleaner way of doing it **(to validate before inserting to the array)**?

The problem is, I can't seem to get the actual **line** in the text file that's being read. That's why I've validated it using the loop index on the array *(int x = numArray[i];)*.

Any help is appreciated, I'm quite new to C programming. Thanks.

```
FILE *myFile = fopen(dataset.txt, "r");
int numArray[15];

if (myFile != NULL) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(numArray); i++)
    {
        //insert int to array
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", &numArray[i]);

        //Validate number
        int x = numArray[i]; 
        if (x > 25) {
            printf("Invalid number found, closing application...");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    //close file
    fclose(myFile); 
}
else {
    //Error opening file
    printf("File cannot be opened!");
}
```

Comment: 1. Check return value of `fscanf` in case file has other characters than just numbers. 2. Why are you putting the numbers in the array anyway, is that a necessary step for later code? Anyway you aren't really *inserting* anything, you are just setting values at array indexes (inserting would generally imply shifting elements in order to make room in the middle).

Comment: Your loop will go out of bounds of the array. The `sizeof` operator gives you the size in ***bytes***, not the number of elements. For an actual array (like your `numArray`) you can get the number of elements by dividing the size of the full array with the size of a single element, i.e. `sizeof numArray / sizeof numArray[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you can store it in a local variable and assign only if valid. But since you're calling `exit(0)` if invalid it doesn't change anything. I suppose you want to `break` from the loop instead.

BTW your loop is wrong. you have to divide `sizeof(numArray)` by the size of one element otherwise you'll loop too many times and you'll crash the machine if there are too many numbers in your input file (yes, I also added a test for end-of-file)

```
if (myFile != NULL) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(numArray[0]); i++)
    {
        int x; 
        //insert int to array
        if (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &x)==0)
        {
            printf("Invalid number found / end of file, closing application...\n");
            exit(0);  // end of file / not a number: stop
        }

        //Validate number
        if (x > 25) {
            printf("Invalid number found, closing application...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        numArray[i] = x;
    }

    //close file
    fclose(myFile); 
}
```